# Insert sql statement in php Error: No database selected

Tags: php, sql, insert

So I'm attempting to make a registration form. I've made a php MySQL class which uses the constructor to make the connection with new MySQLi() for verifyLogin function and mysql_connect() for my addElement function.

The error is with my addElement function, the SQL statement writes out properly but it doesn't seem to connect to the database. I've checked that all the names are correct. Any ideas?

```
<?php

class MySQL {

private $connection;
private $conn;
private $databaseName;

function __construct($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName) {
    $this->connection = new MySQLi($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName)
        or die('PROBLEM CONNECTING TO DATABASE');

    $this->conn = mysql_connect($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
        echo $this->conn;

    $databaseName = $dbName;
}

function verifyLogin($table, $email, $password) {

    $query = "SELECT *
            FROM ?
            WHERE email = ?
            AND password = ?
            LIMIT 1";

    if($statement = $this->connection->prepare($query)) {
        $statement->bind_param('sss', $table, $email, $password);
        $statement->execute();

        if($statement->fetch()) {
            $statement->close();
            return true;    
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

function addElement($table, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $mobile, $password,
                        $faculty, $campus) {


    $query = "INSERT INTO $table (first_name, last_name, email, mobile, password, faculty, campus_location) 
            VALUES('$firstName', '$lastName','$email','$mobile',
            '$password','$faculty','$campus');";
    echo $query;

    mysql_select_db($this->databaseName, $this->conn);

    if(!mysql_query($query)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
    }

    mysql_close($this->connection);
}


}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you using two different extensions???

Comment: @prodigitalson, I imagine that is part of the problem :)

Comment: You mean for the connections? I used the MySQLi one because of a tutorial and that didn't work when I used it for INSERT sql statement so I used the method on w3 schools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select a database in MySQLi, you need to select it like so:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database_name");
```

or

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");
$db->select_db('database_name');
```

as opposed to MySQL:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database_name', $db);
```

MySQLi : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

MySQL  : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: Isn't the "test" parameter on mysqli the database name? So wouldn't using the select_db method afterwards be redundant?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I've updated the answer. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the mysql and the mysqli php drivers.

Since the mysql driver is deprecated I would suggest going with the mysqli.

PHP Documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Good Overview to get you started:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54239-introduction-to-mysqli-and-prepared-statements/